# r count values in rows after dcast

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2

I want to `sum` all values in a row of a dataframe after performing a `dcast` operation from the `reshape2` package. Problem is that all values are the same (10) and are the sum of all rows combined. Values should be 4,2,4
Example data with code:

```
df <- data.frame(x = as.factor(c("A","A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C","C")),
                 y = as.factor(c("AA","AB","AA","AC","BB","BA","CC","CC","CC","CD")),
                 z = c("var1","var1","var2","var1","var2","var1","var1","var2","var2","var1"))

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(x,y) %>%
  summarise(num = n()) %>%
  ungroup()

df3 <- dcast(df2,x~y, fill = 0 )

df3$total <- sum(df3$AA,df3$AB,df3$AC,df3$BA,df3$BB,df3$CC,df3$CD)
```

Answer (score 1):

`sum` gives you 1 combined value and that value is repeated for all other rows.

```
sum(df3$AA,df3$AB,df3$AC,df3$BA,df3$BB,df3$CC,df3$CD)
#[1] 10
```

You need `rowSums` to get sum of each row separately.

```
df3$total <- rowSums(df3[-1])
```

---

Here is a simplified `tidyverse` approach starting from `df` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  count(x, y, name = 'num') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = y, values_from = num, values_fill = 0) %>%
  mutate(total = rowSums(select(., AA:CD)))

#  x        AA    AB    AC    BA    BB    CC    CD total
#  <fct> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
#1 A         2     1     1     0     0     0     0     4
#2 B         0     0     0     1     1     0     0     2
#3 C         0     0     0     0     0     3     1     4
```

Answer (score 1):

We can specify the `values_fn` in `pivot_wider` and also use `adorn_totals` from `janitor`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(janitor)
df %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = y, values_from = z, values_fill = 0, 
         values_fn = length) %>%
   adorn_totals("col")
```

-output

```
# x AA AB AC BB BA CC CD Total
# A  2  1  1  0  0  0  0     4
# B  0  0  0  1  1  0  0     2
# C  0  0  0  0  0  3  1     4
```

---

Or using `base R` with `xtabs` and `addmargins`

```
addmargins(xtabs(z ~ x + y, transform(df, z = 1)), 2)
#   y
#x   AA AB AC BA BB CC CD Sum
#  A  2  1  1  0  0  0  0   4
#  B  0  0  0  1  1  0  0   2
#  C  0  0  0  0  0  3  1   4
```